# How to add background image in material-ui drawer component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have tried these two methods, but neither work.

Method one: change Drawer component directly.

```
    <Drawer
      style={{backgroundImage: url('../../public/images/sideList.jpg')}}>
      <div>
        <SideList/>
      </div>
    </Drawer>
```

Method two: add background-image property for a nested div.

```
    <Drawer>
      <BackgroundImageDiv>
        <SideList/>
      </BackgroundImageDiv>
    </Drawer>
```

Answer (score 8):

Please add background image url for your drawer style class

```
import drawerImage from "../../resources/images/drawer.jpg";

const styles = theme => ({
    drawerPaper: {
      backgroundImage: `url(${drawerImage})`

    },
})
```

drawer component sample

```
<Drawer classesName={classes.drawerPaper} />
```

Comment: Minor correction, ``` backgroundImage: `url(${drawerImage})` ``` instead of drawerPaper

Answer (score 0):

In MUI 5.0+, you can do it with this:

Example of the navigation drawer with background image and opacity in black, like [this](https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard-react/?_ga=2.85349529.165079111.1634000887-1984657256.1633455190#/admin/dashboard).

```
<Drawer
                    variant="permanent"
                    sx={ {
                        display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' },
                        '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
                            boxSizing: 'border-box',
                            width: DRAWER_WIDTH,
                            backgroundImage: 'url(/img/meteorImpact.jpg)',
                            position: 'absolute',
                            backgroundSize: 'cover',
                            backgroundPosition: 'center center',
                            '&:before': {
                                position: 'absolute',
                                width: '100%',
                                height: '100%',
                                content: '""',
                                display: 'block',
                                background: '#000',
                                opacity: '0.6'
                            }
                        }
                    } }
                    open
                >
                    { brand }
                    { drawerItems }
                </Drawer>
```